# Working with Smart Cards over Windows 10 PE

Tags: c++, windows-10, smartcard, smartcard-reader, winpe

I'm trying to develop an c++ project that must work with smart cards (and smart cards readers) - this project had to work over Windows 10 pe- but when I tried to test the project I got an error SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE from the method SCardEstablishContext. (however- when I tried it on standard Windows 10 it works fine)

Anyway, I wonder if it's possible (and how) at all to work with smart cards over Windows10PE? So if anyone has some suggestions or more experienced with Windows10PE, working with SmartCards or windows at all I will be really glad for some help here!!

really thanks! :)

Comment: Did you check, whether the *smartcard* service is installed and running?

Comment: I didn’t find ScardSrv in the Registry so I guess it isn’t installed